# React js - I want that autocomplete should search values with primaryText and SecondaryText

Tags: reactjs

I have defined the following autocomplete code in my project.

```
    <Autocomplete
      id={id}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className="md-cell md-cell--4"
      data={service_list}
      filter={Autocomplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
      onAutocomplete={create_url_after_autocomplete}
   />
```

The data that I am providing to autocomplete is:

```
    service_list = [
                    {
                      value : "1",
                      primaryText : "Driver Verification",
                      secondaryText : "Police Verification"
                    },
                    {
                      value : "2",
                      primaryText : "Maid Verification",
                      secondaryText : "Police Verification"
                    }
                   ]
```

Now as i type something in my autocomplete it only shows suggestions from my primaryText but I also want that If I type Police Verification in my autocomplete it should show both the suggestions.

I have no idea about this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Autocomplete`?

Comment: Which framework or library are u using?

Comment: Autocomplete is a component in react js that is just like tetfield but the only difference is that it shows suggestions from the data as soon as  you type something in it. @YuryTarabanko

Comment: `<Autocomplete>` is not part of regular React. What library are you using?

Comment: @MayankBansal I know what "autocomplete" is. But I have no idea which exact autocomplete implementation you are currently using. There is no Autocomplete comming with React itself.

Comment: I am using MD Lauren Material Design library. @GautamNaik

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is necessary to use an array -

```
{service_list.map(item=> (
 <Autocomplete
   id={item.value}
   key={item.value}
   primaryText={item.primaryText}
   secondaryText={item.secondaryText}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   className="md-cell md-cell--4"
   data={service_list}
   filter={Autocomplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
   onAutocomplete={create_url_after_autocomplete}

/>)}
```